# How to center two left rows vertically in grid?

Tags: html, css

I'm using grid to achieve this design (desktop is 1st image, mobile is 2nd image):
[image: Desktop Design]
[image: Mobile Design]

Problem is, the two left div text isn't divided evenly so the text is skewed to the top, rather than dynamically in the center. Tried using flex, but it doesn't work because of the mobile design.

Comment: Have you tried `justify-items: center;` in the mobile layout's grid?

Comment: @isaactfa yes. The biggest issue is getting the image to be 2nd in order.  Because if I use a flex box to the main title and subtitle, they're essentially together.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? If so what version?

Comment: Also please include your code in order for us to be able to debug it.

Comment: In flexbox you can use the `order` property (although that's not always the best option) and in grid you can easily change the position with the `grid-area` property.

Comment: Is [this](https://codepen.io/isaactfa/pen/wvyvxXL) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple opportunities to achieve this. I think using grid system is quite good idea. But if you like simple solution you can use media queries.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;  
  gap: 10%;
}

.txt {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;  
  align-items: center;  
  flex-direction: column;  
}

.mobile {
  display: none;
}
.desktop {
  display: flex;
}

@media (max-width: 60rem) { 
  .mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="flex">
  <div class="txt desktop">
    <h1 class="main-title">Main title</h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div>
  <h1 class="main-title mobile">Main title</h1>  
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300"
  class="hero-image">
  <h2 class="subtitle mobile">Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
</main>
```